# How to log soap requests response time with cxf on the client side?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using `cxf` to build a client on a `soap` webservice.
Is there any cxf interceptor feature that could automatically measures and logs the webservice response time?

I'm already using `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor` for logging the xml content itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF has some awesome out of the box features that can help monitor the response times. 
For this the JMX will need to be enabled.

Refer: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jmx-management.html

The management api is part of the cxf-rt-management.jar.The features can be enabled against the target endpoint that needs to be monitored using:

```
org.apache.cxf.management.interceptor.ResponseTimeFeature
```

This will make use of the following interceptors:

- `org.apache.cxf.management.interceptor.ResponseTimeMessageInInterceptor`
- `org.apache.cxf.management.interceptor.ResponseTimeMessageOutInterceptor`

Comment: This looks promising, but how can I enable the ResponseTimeFeature when using only annotation-based configuration without any xml files (and I don't want to introduce xml files just for a monitoring feature)..?